# Keep old variable values in label field

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable that changes value in a while -loop. It is basically like this:

```
    var n=0
    while n < 50{
        var textArr = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n00")
        var rad: String = textArr[n]

        if user_event == 1{
            if rad.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("  event") != nil{
                println(rad)
           label.text=rad
            }
        }
```

In my output -window I get all the different "rad"-values written out, but in the label field I only see the last value of the rad variable. How can I change this so the label field writes out all the rad-values without overwriting when the variable changes?

Comment: Any particular programming language ?

Comment: Im sorry, Im using Xcode and swift. :)

Comment: OK - fixed your tags for you - take care with this in future if you want people to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add new value to existing value

```
label.text = "\(label.text) \(rad)"
```

or

```
label.text += rad
```

Comment: Oh my, it worked! Thank you for the help, easy solution for an issue I've tried to fix for a while.